# Is it possible to integrate Yandex Maps in a Xamarin iOS project?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, yandex, yandex-maps

These are some of my findings but not able to implement the same.
I also looked Yandex app-centric but was not able to add packages due to version conflict issues.

https://tech.yandex.com/maps/mapkit/

https://appmetrica.yandex.com/docs/mobile-sdk-dg/concepts/xamarin-plugin.html

Comment: Looks promising, what kind of conflicts are you running into?

Comment: I think thier documentation is better than most other things that you need to implement have you tried playing with the dll's installing different versions to see if any at all work for you?

Comment: For easy installation they provide a NuGet package you can use: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Yandex.Metrica.Xamarin/ It doesn't seem to have any dependencies, so if you encounter any issues, it would help a lot if you provided some more context. I.e. package restore log.

Comment: @RickDavies not able to find Nuget Packages in Xamarin ios for Yandex maps. (Xamarin.Yandex.iOS package not found).

Comment: @FreakyAli we are not able to find the dlls too. If there is any references for nug packages in xamarin.ios for Yandex Maps please share... I referred to: The Below URL is for Xamarin.iOS.
https://github.com/pocheshire/Xamarin.YandexMaps.iOS   but not able to build the project since packages not available..Error: index mapkit not found

Comment: @Cheesebaron yes you right but it is only for analytics purpose there is no mention of maps.I did go through the document.I have got the one source code git hub for Yandex Maps Integration for Xamarin.Forms below URL:

[https://github.com/yandexmobile/metrica-plugin-xamarin]

Comment: @VinayakNair I am unable to find Yandex Maps on their official website itself!! And I mean for mobile I can find js examples.